# SVN - how to get a list of all commits on a branch and from branches merged into that branch?

Tags: git, svn

I'm new to SVN and am having a really hard time getting information I'm used to getting in Git.

What I really need is a way to, given a 'parent' branch, get all commits made on that branch and on other branches that may have been merged into the parent branch. Now, I don't need the list of commits from head on the parent branch to the beginning of time. I can figure out what revision I need to go back to (base commit), but need to throw out any commits forward in time from that base commit that are not in the parent branch (either committed directly to or merged into the parent branch).

This can be scripted and stored somewhere if need be. It doesn't have to run on the fly in a single command. This is basically to validate the list of commits going into a release branch is the correct list of commits, and the results will be used to update Jira tickets to match commits.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you are overcomplicating things after being used to git. It's much user-friendly in Subversion. Just run the command `svn log --use-merge-history --verbose <BRANCH-URL>`.

E.g. `svn log -g -v https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.9.x/`

See [SVNBook | `svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

Comment: I looked absolutely everywhere for `--use-merge-history` This is exactly what i was looking for a half hour for. Thank you!

Comment: Nice answer. You may want to remove the ending `.` for clarity.

Comment: @PJ_Finnegan thank you! I've just removed the ending dot character.

Comment: or just . instead of repository URL when being in the repository directory